# showing three factors in line graph

Tags: r, legend, linegraph, errorbar

I am trying to make a line graph with three factors. In addition, I would like to have my legend labels have two symbols.

This is the published example I am trying to emulate....

[image: desired style]

as you can see, each label has two symbols, one for each level of one factor. Furthermore, the same factor is shown twice on the same panel for each level, i.e. cultivar with two different levels of a factor.

I am trying to make one panel at a time, I will join them later and put the legend at the top like in the above example.

Here is the start of my attempt....

[image: My attempt]

I have got my points on the graph, though im baffled as to how to make a line join through each cultivar, show error bars, and make the legend similar to the above example. I want the legend to have one label for each cultivar, but with two symbols, one symbol for Waterlogging and one for Non-waterlogging

```
structure(list(pot = c(41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L
), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Dinninup", "Riverina", 
"Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35), form = c(2.81, 2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 3.18, 2.57, 2.9, 
3, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 3.06, 3.01, 3.01, 2.77, 2.95, 2.36, 
2.91, 2.38, 3.33, 3.19, 3.17, 3.16, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 3.71, 3.11, 
2.7, 2.92, 1.93, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 3.34, 2.75, 2.52, 1.88, 
1.19, 0.57, 0.64, 0.66, 1.13, 1.28, 0.85, 0.96, 1.34, 2.14, 0.63, 
1.27, 1.13, 0.64, 1.21, 1.95, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 1.06, 1.07, 
1.05, 0.8, 1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.98, 1.27, 1.01, 1, 1.16, 
0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 1.03, 1.13, 0.79, 0.6)), row.names = 41:120, class = "data.frame")


library(Rmisc)
library(ggplot2)

tglf3 <- summarySE(yar, measurevar="form", groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"),na.rm=TRUE)

ggplot(tglf3, aes(x=P, y=form)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Waterlogging), 
shape=factor(cultivar)),size=3.5,position=position_dodge(1))+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se),colour="black", width=.1,position=position_dodge(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this approaching what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
tglf3 <- summarySE(yar, measurevar="form", groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Mostly, making use of `dplyr::group_by` can solve the point-line pairing:

```
tglf3 %>% 
  group_by(cultivar) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=P, y=form, colour=Waterlogging, shape=cultivar)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), colour="black", width=.6) +
  geom_point(size=3.5) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.direction="vertical")
```

[image]

---

More formatting using `scale_x_manual`:

```
tglf3 %>% 
  unite(new, cultivar, Waterlogging, sep = ', ') %>% 
  group_by(new) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=P, y=form, colour=new, shape=new, linetype=new)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), colour="black", width=.6) +
  geom_line(color="black") + 
  geom_point(size=3.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging",
                      labels = c("Riverina, Non-waterlogged", "Riverina, Waterlogged", "Yarloop, Non-waterlogged", "Yarloop, Waterlogged"),
                      values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging",
                     labels = c("Riverina, Non-waterlogged", "Riverina, Waterlogged", "Yarloop, Non-waterlogged", "Yarloop, Waterlogged"),
                     values = c(19, 19, 17, 17)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging", values=c("longdash", "solid", "longdash", "solid")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.direction="vertical") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]

---

Without `%>%`:

```
tglf4 <- unite(data = tglf3, new, cultivar, Waterlogging, sep = ', ')
tglf5 <- group_by(.data = tglf4, new)

ggplot(tglf5, aes(x=P, y=form, colour=new, shape=new, linetype=new)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), colour="black", width=.6) +
geom_line(color="black") + 
geom_point(size=3.5) +
scale_colour_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging",
                    labels = c("Riverina, Non-waterlogged", "Riverina, Waterlogged", "Yarloop, Non-waterlogged", "Yarloop, Waterlogged"),
                    values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red")) +
scale_shape_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging",
                   labels = c("Riverina, Non-waterlogged", "Riverina, Waterlogged", "Yarloop, Non-waterlogged", "Yarloop, Waterlogged"),
                   values = c(19, 19, 17, 17)) +
scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging", values=c("longdash", "solid", "longdash", "solid")) +
theme_classic() +
theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.direction="vertical") +
guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

---

Using `facet_grid` (example using fake data):

```
tglf3 %>% 
  mutate(
    form = form * 1.5
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(tglf3, .id = 'species') %>% # Add fake data to the real data as an example
  mutate(
    species = case_when(species == 1 ~ 'O. sativus',
                        T ~ 'O. compressus')
  ) %>% 
  unite(new, cultivar, Waterlogging, sep = ', ') %>% 
  group_by(new) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=P, y=form, colour=new, shape=new, linetype=new)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=form-se, ymax=form+se), colour="black", width=.6) +
  geom_line(color="black") + 
  geom_point(size=3.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging",
                      labels = c("Riverina, Non-waterlogged", "Riverina, Waterlogged", "Yarloop, Non-waterlogged", "Yarloop, Waterlogged"),
                      values = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging",
                     labels = c("Riverina, Non-waterlogged", "Riverina, Waterlogged", "Yarloop, Non-waterlogged", "Yarloop, Waterlogged"),
                     values = c(19, 19, 17, 17)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Cultivar, Waterlogging", values=c("longdash", "solid", "longdash", "solid")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.direction="vertical") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  facet_grid(.~species)
```

[image]

Comment: That is awesome. Is it possible to change the legend so it has a similar structure to the example I posted above?

Comment: Same structure as in two symbols per legend label

Comment: ...or rather making the symbols represent what is actually shown in the graph. So the circle will be two colours, and the triangle two colours....

Comment: I'm probably interpreting the example incorrectly, but that kind of thing can be done using the scale manual functions: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html. There's an example in the edited answer. Also, you have to (?) use `tidyr::unite` beforehand to combine the two variables.

Comment: what does the symbol "%>%" mean and do?

Comment: ....Is there a way to write the script in the format I used without it.

Comment: Do you see in the example graph I posted above, it looks like they have combined two plots together, then used a common legend for both. Do you think this is possible in ggplot?

Comment: @EliottReed Sorry, `%>%` is the forward pipe operator from the magrittr package: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/. I'll add `library(tidyverse)` – that will also load `tidyr`, `dplyr`, `ggplot2`, etc., which should be all you need (after `library(Rmisc)`.